# count lines of code for each class in a python file?

Tags: python, inspect, lines-of-code

I'm trying to find the count of lines of codes within a class in a python file .. I used the len(inspect.getsourcelines(b)[0]) to return the number of lines of code for each class in the file but the problem it counts comments and doc string in addition to the code lines .. is there any way to discard the comments and doc string??

```
import inspect
import foo

for a,b in inspect.getmembers(foo): 
    if inspect.isclass(b):
        print(a)
        print(len(inspect.getsourcelines(b)[0]))
```

Comment: You can access the docstring for each class and function via `__doc__` and count docstring lines yourself, but I don't know of a way to do that with comments.

Comment: it is better to include comments in the lines of code count.

Answer (score 2):

You may just have to parse out the comments yourself from the result of `getsourcelines`. If you ignore multiline comments, this just means checking if the first non-whitespace character is `#`. For multiline comments using triple quotes, you can do something similar while keeping track of whether or not you're in a comment block.

Comment: I tried to do so but I couldn't find any way that can work ... do you have any idea of how to do so??

Comment: Ignoring multiline comments, `len([line for line in inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0] if not line.strip().startswith('#')])` where foo is the object you're inspecting.

Comment: If this is something you've tried, it would be good to post what you've tried that didn't work.